# How to calculate the space complexity of memory usage at each iteration

Tags: space-complexity

```
def afunction(list):
    for i in list:
         temp = [elem for elem in list]
    return 0
```

In the above funciton, at each iteration, the function will spend extra memory to create a new list temp, that the space use is O(N). There are N such iterations, does that mean the space complexity of this function is O(N^2)?

Could anyone explain the space complexity of this function please?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the loop, there are at most 2 intermediate lists in flight:

- The list already bound to `temp`;
- The list being constructed to replace it.

Both of these have length N, so the space complexity of this function is O(2N) or just O(N).